# #LATEST does not work with Jenkins Artifactory Plugin

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, artifacts

I am using Generic-Artifactory Integration to try and pull a file from Artifactory but I keep getting a message saying its not found. If I use a specific build number it works, but when I use #LATEST it does not pull the latest version.

Log Message:

```
Dependency on build [esb_build], number [LATEST], pattern [esb-local:/files/develop/SearchAPI_Lib/*.zip] - [0] results found.
```

The esb_build is the name of the Jenkins Job that build the artifact and pushed it to artifactory.

Resolved Artifact pattern:

```
esb-local:files/develop/SearchAPI_Lib/*.zip@esb_build#LATEST=>${WORKSPACE}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong as to why it is not being found?

Comment: I encountered the same problem yesterday, do you have any idea ?